# SSAS Date Measure Max StringFormat when Null

Tags: formatting, ssas, measure

I have a cube with a measure of type date, performing a max aggregation, where some of the data points have a null value for date. In these cases, the Max value becomes 12/30/1899 which I believe is the earliest expression of a date.

Is there a way to have these appear in the results as blank rather than this bogus date?

I tried to use the measure's StringFormat property with no luck.

Comment: Is it 12/30/1899 or 1/1/1900?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the **NullProcessing** property for your measure to **Preserve**. You can do this in BIDS. Open the project, then the cube, then on the Cube Structure tab expand the measure group and then select the measure. In the properties pane select Source, expand it and you should see the property there. **After you process**, the measure will be NULL instead of the default 0 which gets assigned to NULLs. The 0 then gets cast to a date and becomes 00/01/1900 in Excel.

Comment: I tried this and it did not seem to work. In the BIDS cube browser, the value did change to 12:00:00 AM rather than 12/30/1899, but in excel it is still interpreted as 1/0/1900 0:00. I wonder if a format expression can do this?

Comment: Actaully the change to 12:00:00 AM seems to be due to me removing the formatting, not the NullProcessing change. Preserve seems to have no effect. I did confirm in the data source viewer that the values are Null.

Comment: The change in the formatting is due to you fiddling with the FORMAT_STRING property. However, if you set the NullProcessing to Preserve you should not see anything where you have empty cells. Did you process the whole cube after the change, or did you just deploy the changes?